# Unexpected response code 307 for GET request for local service

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to connect to a localhost web service that I wrote in .net core 2.0. Using the emulator's browser I was able to invoke it and get JSON data back. However, inside my app when I try to get it I'm getting response code 307 back.

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
    String url = String.format("http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/testservice/tickerpnl?ticker=%s&purchaseDate=%s&shares=%s/"
            , tickerText.getText().toString(), dateText.getText().toString(), sharesText.getText().toString());

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try
                    {
                        double pnl = response.getDouble("PNL");
                    } catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

On the stacktrace I'm getting the following:

D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
E/Volley: [403] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 307 for http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/testservice/tickerpnl?ticker=AAPL&purchaseDate=1-1-15&shares=1

Again using the link from the stack trace I was able to get the JSON data back just pasting it into the emulator's browser but somehow it just won't work using JsonObjectRequest.

the requestqueue was initialize as

```
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

Comment: I hit the service as you mentioned, It is taking too much time to get response. First, you need to check why it is taking too much time. Secondly as you said this is working on emulator? If this is the case, you need to check if the device is on the same network as the emulator. Network should be same for local host.

Comment: Sorry I'm alittle confuse, the service I wrote is hosted locally on my machine so I'm not sure what you mean by that. I looked it up in that to reach localhost on my machine I would have to call it on 10.0.2.2. It's working on the emulator's chrome browser but when I call it using JsonObjectRequest inside my app it fails on 307 response code.

Comment: you are using the same network connection as your maching on which emulator is and your device as well?

Comment: yes. They're on the same network, on the same machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the issue was that for .net core I had code that redirect http to https so that's why I was getting the 307 error since I was trying to call it using http

Comment: How did you resolve? Did you get it running under https?